# Parsing error -- Creating an RSS feed with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, rss

Hey guys, I'm creating an rss feed with codeigniter and I get the specific error:
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://mysite.com/feeds/latest

After googling it and not being able to find a solution to my issue (despite a ton of results) I came here for some advice.

I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
```

Followed by my websites title, link, description, pubdate, dc:date tags.

Followed by a foreach statement that loops results like so:

```
<?php foreach($feedResults as $feedItem): ?>
 <item>
       <title><?php echo $feedItem->title; ?></title>
          <link><?php echo site_url('/'.$feedItem->ID) ?></link>
          <guid><?php echo site_url('/'.$feedItem->ID) ?></guid>
    <description>descri[</description>
          <pubDate><?php echo date ('r', $feedItem->time());?></pubDate>
    </item>        
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My codeigniter controller doesn't do much besides retrieve $feedResults, sets the header to :
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
and then passes the results to the view.

Thanks guys.

Comment: it's probably the <description>descri[</description>

Comment: I changed it to static data blah, and still no change.

Answer (score 1):

If you save your RSS feed off with a `.html` extension you'll see that it's not RSS at all, it's an HTML error page:

> #### ErrorException [ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
>
> #### APPPATH/views/feeds_latest_view.php [ 1 ]
>
> ```
> 1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> 2 <rss xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" version="2.0">
> 3   <channel>
> 4 
> 5     <title>Amazon.com Gold Box Deals</title>
> 6     <link>http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox</link>
> ```
>
> 1. {PHP internal call} » MY_Exceptions::shutdown_handler(arguments)

My guess is that you have PHP `short_tags` enabled, which means `<?` is shorthand for `<?php` and opens a PHP code block. PHP is choking when it sees the `<?xml` as it tries to interpret the XML processing directive as a block of PHP code.

To fix this, turn off `short_tags` in php.ini. Or workaround it by writing PHP code to emit the directive:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Location: http://mysite.com/feeds/latest" looks like an HTTP header (location headers are how redirects work). Are you passing a URL that redirects to another URL to an XML parser that can't follow redirects?